# iPhone4 can't access iCloud after upgrade to iOS 7.0.2

Tags: icloud, ios

Software upgrade seems to have worked fine but settings->icloud is disabled.  It used to work fine.

Also FaceTime icon produces  message "Account restriction - this iphone is restricted from creating FaceTime accounts".

Any ideas please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why stop at 7.0.2? wWhy not go all the way to 7.0.4 to make sure that you are current? Otherwise killswitch has the right idea

Answer (score 1):

**Settings > Restrictions > Allow Changes > Accounts**

If disallowed FaceTime appears as you said.
I had the same problem and in looking for the solution managed to figure it out.